# Classic ASP code opens in Visual Studio 2012 but not 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, asp-classic

I'm trying to migrate from VS2012 to VS2015.  I have a need to edit Classic ASP code.

The code opens just fine in VS2012.  It will *not* open in VS2015.  Or, more accurately, when I open it in VS2015, I don't see any code; all I see is a tab with the file name and a big blank blue field where the code should be.

What do I need to set in order to view it?  I can't seem to find this anywhere.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: It works in my VS 2015. Are you seeing this in design, split, or source view? Is this a VS website or project?

Comment: Just use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) for Classic ASP editing its lightweight and full of features.

Comment: @Lankymart are you able to debug classic asp with vs code?

Comment: I'm seeing this in source view.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried reinstalling VS? I'm running VS2017 without any problems, having just upgraded from VS2015, which I ran without issues as well. I'd try a reinstall and see if that resolves the problem.